# How to print 10Digit Long Integer into JSP file?

Tags: java, jsp

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT88T.png)
**Actual Database**
[Website Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM3rz.png)
**Fetching Data from Database into JSP**

```
<td class="invoiceValue"><%=resultSet.getFloat("invoice_id") %></td>
```

I want to print that same 10digit number present in Database into JSP file.
How to fix this?

Comment: why  ... getFloat()  .. seems an int  ,,  so try use a getInt

Answer (score 0):

You can print it like a String, I don't think you are ever gonna make calculations with invoice ids anyway

```
<td class="invoiceValue"><%=resultSet.getString("invoice_id") %></td>
```

It's easier and you don't need to worry about nothing, you will also need to change your data types in your code as well (if you are using Hybernate for example)

Comment: It is showing same, actually in database that column is float..... Any other suggestion can you give?

Comment: Does not make a lot of sense to be float, you'll probably never use the numbers after the dot anyway. You shoud be using a String, or either an Integer (since you have close to 10 characters, you shoud use Bigint instead. [Int types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score -1):

first get the data into long format and then convert it to string.
in cases of java servlet it would look somewhat like
rs.getLong(columnindex/name)+""  // appending empty string will convert long-> string